gradient of 1-norm of a binary vector
I have some flaw in my logic, which I cannot resolve. It is abouth the gradient of the 1-norm of a binary vector.
Let $\mathbf{x} = [x_{1},x_{2},...x_{D}]^{T}$ denote a $D$-dimensional vector and let $||\mathbf{x}||_{1} = \sum_{d=1}^{D} = |x_{d}|$ denote the 1-norm of the vector, i.e., sum of absolutes. In my particular case, the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is a binary vector, i.e., each element $x_{d} = \left\{0,1\right\}$ either equals 0 or 1. For this particular vector the 1-norm can be written as $||\mathbf{x}||_{1} = \mathbf{1}^{T}\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all-ones. My confusion is now when it comes to the calculation of the gradient of the 1-norm with respect to $\mathbf{x}$.
Way 1:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\,||\mathbf{x}||_{1} = \nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\,\mathbf{1}^{T}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{1} 
\end{equation}
(compare with Matrix cookbook (69)
I.e., the gradient is defined for all elements of $\mathbf{x}$ and has the same sign for all elements of $\mathbf{x}$.
Way 2:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\,||\mathbf{x}||_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{1}}\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{2}}\\\vdots\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{D}}\end{bmatrix}||\mathbf{x}||_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{1}}\,||\mathbf{x}||_{1}\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{2}}\,||\mathbf{x}||_{1}\\\vdots\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{D}}\,||\mathbf{x}||_{1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{1}}\,|x_{1}|\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{2}}\,|x_{2}|\\\vdots\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{D}}\,|x_{D}|\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{x_{1}}{|x_{1}|}\\\frac{x_{2}}{|x_{2}|}\\\vdots\\\frac{x_{D}}{|x_{D}|}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where I used the definition of the derivative of the absolute value, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}|x| = \frac{x}{|x|}$ (e.g., shown here:)
I.e., the gradient is defined only  for elements which are unequal to $0$ and has different signs.
Can you help me to resolve this contradiction? Thank you.

In the second method, $\left|x_j\right| = x_j {;;\rm since;} x_j\in{0,1}.;$ Therefore
$$
\frac{d\left|x_j\right|}{dx_j} = \frac{dx_j}{dx_j} = {\tt1}
$$

true, thank you for solving the problem!
